# Does the speed of universal expansion lead to time going backwards?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, faster-than-light, causality, arrow-of-time

After reading that time stops at the speed of light and at event horizons I wondered if when the speed of light is exceeded does time loop backwards ...

The thought struck me too that the term space-expansion might also imply the space between subatomic particles ...

Comment: It seems you're assuming that if time goes slow enough it goes backwards, but I don't see how it follows

Comment: To reopen this post (v5) consider for starters to only ask 1 subquestion per post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question you ask isn't well-posed (whose time is "flowing backwards?") but there's still a clear answer: **no**.

This is because the expansion of space is unconstrained by the speed of light. No physical thing can travel faster than light, but the universe can still expand faster than light because [it's not physical](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/24160/how-could-the-universe-be-a-few-light-years-across-just-1-second-after-the-big-b). Since the expansion of the universe isn't physical, we can also say that the usual special relativity effects such as time dilation don't apply.

Comment: @Wookie not saying the expansion isn't physical, but rather that it isn't a physical object that's expanding. Space itself is expanding; there's nothing made of atoms that's expanding.

Comment: @Wookie The cosmological models that predict expansion apply on large scales only. They assume a uniform distribution of mass & energy everywhere and  do not consider local objects like atoms, or even planets & galaxies. Small-scale objects may not be participating in the expansion, due to local effects.